# What are other possible materials for дурилка?

Tags: словоупотребление, word

Most common usage I have seen for the angling utility дурилка, it is referenced to be made of cardboard which possible would attract fish after getting wet, maybe similar to bread crumbs; but are others materials possible, too?

Comment: Please, rephrase it in order to make it a question related to Russian language. For instance, "в русском языке вилкой может обозначаться любой аналог английской fork или только изделия из алюминия?" is about Russian language, but "из чего делают вилки" is not.

Comment: http://russian_argo.academic.ru/3330/дурилка

Comment: According to ru-wiki, дурилка=angeldon ( in рыболовная снасть context ). 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angeldon - no special condition on what a bait would be, would it be some real food or imitation, cardboard or anything. Additionally, pikes are predators and I do not thing they would go after "bread crumbs"